# I can't run the node.js server using keystone.js framework

Tags: keystonejs

I have source code using `keystone.js`, and I can't run it because of a Mongodb connection error.
This is the code creating Keystone.

```js
const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: process.env.PROJECT_NAME,
  adapter: new Adapter({dbName}),
  mongo: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/',
  sessionStore: new MongoStore({ url: 'mongodb://localhost/' }),
  cookieSecret: 'process.env.COOKIE_SECRET',
  appVersion: {
    version: '1.0.0',
    addVersionToHttpHeaders: false,
    access: false,
  },
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
    sameSite: false
  }
});

...
await keystone.connect()
```

Here are the error details:

```
(node:9928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No MongoDB connection URI specified.
    at resolveAllKeys (E:\Node.JS\frostbets-master-2-20210809T155720Z-001\frostbets-master-2\keystone\node_modules\@keystonejs\utils\dist\utils.cjs.dev.js:51:19)    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Keystone.connect (E:\Node.JS\frostbets-master-2-20210809T155720Z-001\frostbets-master-2\keystone\node_modules\@keystonejs\keystone\lib\Keystone\index.js:450:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9928) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified but it looks like you're on Keystone 5 so I'm going with that assumption.

There are a number of issue in the code you've posted:

- The main problem you have is you're passing `dbName` to init you Adapter but you should be passing the full `mongoUri`.
  That's the source of the specific error you're getting.
  Pretty sure `dbName` was an option at one point but not in the current release of KS5.
  Again, not sure which version you're actually on but if you've updated some packages in an older project, that might be it.
- I'm not sure what the `mongo` key being passed in the Keystone config but I don't think it's valid.
  Any config for Mongo (for the main DB) should be passed to the adapter.
- The syntax you're using to create your `MongoStore` instance has been deprecated for the current version of that package.
  If it works for you leave it, but in the code below I've used the more recent `MongoStore.create()` syntax.
- In your code you have `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/` (under the `mongo` key, which I think is ignored) and `mongodb://localhost/` for the `sessionStore`.
  For most systems this will refer to the same DB though it's not clear if that's intentional in your case.
  In my code I've put the sessions in a separate DB (`my-app-sessions`) but that's optional.
- Your config uses the literal string `'process.env.COOKIE_SECRET'` as the cookie secret, not the *value* in the `COOKIE_SECRET` environment var.
  This is almost certainly not what you want.

To solve these problems, you probably want something close to this:

```js
const { Keystone } = require('@keystonejs/keystone');
const { GraphQLApp } = require('@keystonejs/app-graphql');
const { AdminUIApp } = require('@keystonejs/app-admin-ui');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const { MongooseAdapter: Adapter } = require('@keystonejs/adapter-mongoose');

const keystone = new Keystone({
  name: process.env.PROJECT_NAME,
  adapter: new Adapter({ mongoUri: 'mongodb://localhost/my-app' }),
  sessionStore: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost/my-app-sessions' }),
  cookieSecret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  appVersion: {
    version: '1.0.0',
    addVersionToHttpHeaders: false,
    access: false,
  },
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
    sameSite: false
  }
});

// ... 

module.exports = {
  keystone,
  apps: [new GraphQLApp(), new AdminUIApp({ name: process.env.PROJECT_NAME, enableDefaultRoute: true })],
};
```

In this code I've left the standard exports at the bottom rather than calling `keystone.connect()` directly so I can run it with `yarn keystone dev`.

Tested with..

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@keystonejs/adapter-mongoose": "^11.2.2",
  "@keystonejs/app-admin-ui": "^7.5.2",
  "@keystonejs/app-graphql": "^6.3.2",
  "@keystonejs/keystone": "^19.3.3",
  "connect-mongo": "^4.4.1"
}
```